# Solution of linear differential equation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$df/dx=(f(x)+x)x,    f(0)=0$$

Show that there is a unique solution to the dierential equation and  find the solution.

This may be linear differential equation but $f(x)$ only including $x$ so this equation has one variable. If we integrate both direction of equality then how can we integrate $f(x)x$? because we cannot know that content of $f(x)$. I am confused.

Comment: Did the solution below make sense and you worked it out?

Comment: I found f(x)=-x²-2/x    is it true?

Comment: That does not look correct, especially with the IF I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write this as:

$$\dfrac{df}{dx} - x~f(x) = x^2, ~f(0) = 0$$

Now use an integrating factor:

$$\mu(x) = e^{-\int x~dx} = e^{-x^2/2}$$

You should be able to take it from here (result is a bit nasty).

Comment: Needs a TU-UV-NOW! +1

Comment: I agree - Even as a newcomer way back, I posted on meta about upvotes and non-upvotes and what it seemed they really mean (and what they do not mean!) It's only gotten worse over time! Even knowing that, it's hard not to get discouraged sometimes. :-(

Comment: Do you get off two days this week (since not last week?) You deserve a little respite! In the meantime, good luck!!